# Google Map Angular9 error with opening info window, getAnchor() is not found

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using this [google map angular component](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/google-maps-as-an-angular-component) tutorial and it's working pretty good! **BUT** opening up an info window throws an exception.

Here is my code that calls "this.infoWindow.open" method on a "MapInfoWindow" component from the npm package.

```js
import {
  MapInfoWindow,
  MapMarker,
  GoogleMap
} from '@angular/google-maps';

export class YogabandEventsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MapInfoWindow, {
    static: false
  }) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow;
  @ViewChild(GoogleMap, {
    static: false
  }) googleMap: GoogleMap;


  openInfo(marker: MapMarker, content) {
    this.infoContent = content;
    this.infoWindow.open(marker);
  }
}
```

```html
<google-map [options]="options" [zoom]="zoom" [center]="center" class="h-100" height="100%" width="100%">
  <map-marker #markerElem *ngFor="let marker of markers" (mapClick)="openInfo(markerElem, marker.info)" [position]="marker.position" [label]="marker.label" [title]="marker.title" [options]="marker.options">
  </map-marker>
  <map-info-window>{{ infoContent }}</map-info-window>
</google-map>
```

When

> infoWindow.open(marker)

is called it enters

> google-maps.js // line 1122

but receives an error on line 1122, because there is no "getAnchor()" method

```
this.infoWindow.open(this._googleMap.googleMap, anchor ? anchor.getAnchor() : undefined);
```

```js
   // in google-maps.js 
open(anchor) {
  this._assertInitialized();
  this._elementRef.nativeElement.style.display = '';
  this.infoWindow.open(this._googleMap.googleMap, anchor ? anchor.getAnchor() : undefined); // line 1122
}
```

I looked through the google docs and I don't see any "getAnchor" method.

Here is what I see in the debugger when setting a breakpoint in my component.

[image]

Here is what it shows in the debug console when I look at 'marker', so it has values and is instantiated!

[image]

I can copy and paste the whole thing but it's long.

Here is another pic of debug console, inside google-maps.js file, trying to call the getAnchor() with no luck becasue it doesn't exist.

[image]

Comment: You did a great job articulating the problem that I was having following the same tutorial.  Thanks for the detail and effort.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Found the answer.

Looked at the repo on Github and at an example. It was different than the tutorial from the link I posted above.

https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps#readme

Map marker needed to have this prop

```html
<map-marker 
  #somemarker="mapMarker" // not #markerElem like from the link
  (mapClick)="openInfoWindow(somemarker, marker.info)">
</map-marker>
```

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, turns out [a recent change](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/19641) that changed it from a component into a directive broke the old code (despite the claim in that PR that it wouldn't be a breaking change).